# How to change rpc url programatically in MetaMask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I have custom sidechain network and want to change rpc url, without changing a `chainId`. Is this possible to do programatically? Like `"Provider.setRpcUrl(...)"`.

I know there is `wallet_addEthereumChain` method, but it triggers prompts and asks user to change a network. Is there a way to change network rpc url without prompts?

Comment: Unlikely, changing the network provider without the user noticing would be a security vulnerability. In your case it is better to use the same URL and a proxy/balancer underneath.